# Android studio shared preferences highscore reset after restarting the app

Tags: java, android, preferences, shared

I'm trying to get my app to save my highscore after I close the app and have tried some of the SharedPreference tutorials. But my highscore keeps resetting every time I restart the app. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Blackapps helped me fix my code. It works now!

```
TextView RecordHigh2, RecordHigh2A;
static public int RecordHigh_i = 0;
static public int RecordHigh_A = 0;
public static final String myPrefsKey = "MyPrefsKey";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistics);


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(myPrefsKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    int A = sharedPreferences.getInt("test", -1);
    if(sharedPreferences.getInt("Highscore", -1) < RecordHigh_i){
        editor.putInt("Highscore", RecordHigh_i);
        editor.commit();
    } else{
        RecordHigh_i = sharedPreferences.getInt("Highscore", -1);
    }

    if(sharedPreferences.getInt("HighscoreA", -1) < RecordHigh_A){
        editor.putInt("HighscoreA", RecordHigh_A);
        editor.commit();
    } else{
        RecordHigh_A = sharedPreferences.getInt("HighscoreA", -1);
    }

    RecordHigh2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RecordHigh);
    RecordHigh2.setText("Highscore:  " + RecordHigh_i);

    RecordHigh2A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RecordHighA);
    RecordHigh2A.setText("Highscore Image:  " + RecordHigh_A);
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("Highscore", RecordHigh_i);
        editor.commit();
    };


};
```

Comment: Well you do not read the value back in onCreate.

Comment: `TextView RecordHigh;
static public int RecordHigh = 0;` Two variables with the same name? And why static? And why public?

Comment: @blackapps

I see that I made a mistake into copying the code, I had removed certain parts of it to simplify it as I have two different kinds of high scores. I've edited the code now.

I made it public because the value comes from a different activity

Comment: You are still not reading your value back.

Comment: `made it public because the value comes from a different activity` Thought that you put them in shared preferences.